# Pageview trigger not firing in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, pageviews

I'm trying to fire a pageview trigger whenever the manage staff page of my website is viewed. I tried to do it using the PageView trigger and using Page URL equals https://workex.jobs/manage-staff. The manage staff page can be opened from the home screen by clicking on Manager Staff button on the header.
Link to the home page - https://workex.jobs/
Link to the page I'm trying to monitor - https://workex.jobs/manage-staff
The pageview trigger is not fired when I click on manage staff button on the header which opens the page I'm tracking (https://workex.jobs/manage-staff). But, the trigger is only fired when I refresh the manage staff page. I want to know why the pageview trigger does not fire when I click on the button that opens the page whose URL I'm tracking?
[enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pageview trigger doesn't work on navigations because your site is an SPA. A single page application. It implies that there are no real pageloads on navigations. On a hard refresh or when you navigate to that page directly and not as a result of site navigation, a pageview is issued.

You just want to add a history change trigger to your existing pageview trigger. This one: [image]

And apply your additional trigger page filters or it will fire on every navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same case with the web app and it hasn't fired when I choose Page View.
But with History Change it works perfectly. Thank you @BNazaruk

[image: 1]